# A convenient way to update a project on server

Tags: node.js, automation, updates

There is a project (node.js - although it's not important), which is developed on the local machine and is periodically transferred to the server.
In principle, I could simply erase the project folder on the server each time and replace it with a new one - uploaded from the local machine.
The matter is, that some folders (specifically: node_modules), I do not need to rewrite. So I have to manually create an archive, excluding unnecessary folders from it. And on the server, too, pre-erase everything except for some folders and only then replace.
How can I automate this procedure?
(On the local machine - windows, on the server - Linux)

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the changes directly from your repo.

I do it like this:

I have different branches for different environments like dev, stage and production.

I commit the changes to the branch and pull that on the server.

This way, you don't need to commit unnecessary stuff (like node_modules, credentials etc) to your repo.

You can also easily automate this using CI tools. Look up CI tools.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't use github for this project.

Comment: @s976 If you don't use git, I dunno any good, advisable way to do that. You should use git. How do you manage versions?

Comment: I do use git, but don't use github (since I don't need it and I don't want to share this project)

Comment: @s976 make a private repo

Comment: $7 per month :)

Comment: @s976 You can use bitbucket instead of github. It gives you free private repo.